# Capturing response in spring Webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

Is there a way to capture response body in spring Webflux. I understand that its against the principles of reactive, however I would need to capture the body and return response. I am using ExchangeFilterFunction.

```
 public Optional<ExchangeFilterFunction> buildEnricher() {

    return Optional.of(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .flatMap(body -> {
                        System.out.println(body);
                        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
                    });
    }));
```

This will end up consuming the body and sending an empty client
response. Is there anyway I can send the body back too ?

Comment: Could you please add your code or at least a part of it and show us what have you done till now.

Comment: please explain why you need to capture them

Comment: I need to store all the responses and would like to do it the moment exchange is done and I get a clientresponse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can choose to clone the client response.

```
ClientResponse responseClone = ClientResponse.from(clientResponse)
```

You can now drain the body from `responseClone` and return `Mono.just(clientResponse)`

Comment: It currently is deprecated and returns `ClientResponse.Builder`.

Comment: ClientResponse.from is already deprecated.